# VBA code to change linked picture image name , within Powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a Powerpoint with images inserted using Link and Insert.
I need to change the file names that they link to.

I haven't got access to the source folder.

Therefore need to make the change to via VBA.

I can change the folder location, just not the name of the file.

All that needs changing is the 'Doncaster' to 'London'

- X:\Central\Buildings\District\Images\Forecast_Doncaster.png
  X:\Central\Buildings\District\Images\History_Doncaster.png
  X:\Central\Buildings\District\Images\Current_Doncaster.png

I tried but it doesn't work

```
submarket ="London"
sh.TextFrame.TextRange = Replace(sh.TextFrame.TextRange, "Doncaster", submarket
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted will change the text in the shape but not the link to a picture.  For that you need something more like this:

```
Sub Test()
    Call EditLink(ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1), ".png", ".jpg")
End Sub

Sub EditLink(oSh As Shape, strOriginalText As String, strNewText As String)
    With oSh.LinkFormat
        .SourceFullName = Replace(.SourceFullName, strOriginalText, strNewText)
    End With
End Sub
```

In this example, I'm changing the link to point to a JPG of the same name as the original file which is a PNG.  Modify as needed to change directory names for  your project

Answer (score 0):

A slight amendment to  Steve's answer which I used and it worked! thank you.

```
   ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide s.SlideIndex
    Call EditLink(sh, "Doncaster", "London")
```

Comment: You probably don't need the .GoToSlide, by the way.  Unless you actually do want to have PowerPoint display that slide right then.